# ASP.NET Core 6 Azure AD authentication and certificate mTLS together

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-6.0

I have website I created in ASP.NET Core 6 (hosted in an Azure App Service) that uses our Azure AD for authentication. I would really like to further lock this down by using Cert authentication as well so users can only access the site from devices that have a certain cert installed.

I can find lots of examples of both methods but none using both together.

Has any one got any experience of using both, how did you set it up?

Here is the MS example of using cert auth on its own
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth?tabs=azurecli

Thanks in advance
C

Update 1
Here is the program.cs code in my app with the azure ad setup

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<dbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("XXXXXX")
                    ));

builder.Services.AddScoped<LicenseService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<SettingsService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
    {
        options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
        options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();


app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    var nonceBytes = new byte[32];
    rng.GetBytes(nonceBytes);
    var scriptNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(nonceBytes);
    context.Items.Add("ScriptNonce", scriptNonce);

    rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    nonceBytes = new byte[32];
    rng.GetBytes(nonceBytes);
    var styleNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(nonceBytes);
    context.Items.Add("StyleNonce", styleNonce);


    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", string.Format("default-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; base-uri 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-{1}'", scriptNonce, styleNonce));
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", string.Format("default-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; base-uri 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-{1}'", scriptNonce, styleNonce));
    }

    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1; mode=block");
    //context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"); added to web config for static files
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "same-origin");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies", "none");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Permissions-Policy", "accelerometer=(), camera=(), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), payment=(), usb=()");
    await next();
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: TLS is used for establishing an encryption key before a HTTP request is sent.  Authentication is used after the connection is completed.  The two are exclusive since one is done before the connection is completed and the other after the connection is completed.

Comment: @jdweng Hi, hope its clear in the question, but i am not talking about the server TLS cert, but a client cert that the users browser/device has installed. so only devices i have given the my 'client' cert to can access the site. see the link for more info

Comment: As mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth?tabs=azurecli#aspnet-5-aspnet-core-31-sample) which you have provided, we need to configure `UseCertificateForwarding` in our `Program.cs` file.

Comment: Your link is TLS which is not Authentication.  The link you provided is misleading to call TLS Authentication.  TLS is used to establish a secure encrypted connection between client and server.  Authentication is performed after the connection is completed and is a login to the server.  TLS a certificate block is sent from server to client containing names of possible certificates.  The client then looks up the names in the stores to find matching certificate.  The client has an option to choose any matching name or only one name.  You want the client to choose one specific certificate name.

Comment: @CraigWalker Could you please share the code Repo which u have done Azure AD Authentication, so that it will be easy to configure and add the certificate related code.

Comment: Added my code in the edit. many thanks @Harshitha

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a couple of things here.

Configure Kestrel configuration options to AllowCertificates and if required introduce additional  client certificate validation

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
    {
        options.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
        options.ClientCertificateValidation = (certificate, chain, errors) =>
        {
            // TODO: Additional client certificate validation logic here
            return true;
        };
    });
});
```

Add Header and Certificate forwarding

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default. Clear that restriction to enable this explicit configuration.
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
 
// Configure the application to client certificate forwarded the frontend load balancer
builder.Services.AddCertificateForwarding(options => 
{ 
    options.CertificateHeader = "X-ARR-ClientCert"; 
});

// builder.Services.AddAuthentication...
```

Add Certificate Authentication

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        // Default is Chained only, All is required Chained | SelfSigned
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        options.ValidateCertificateUse = false;
 
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
             OnCertificateValidated = context =>
             {
                 // TODO: Further validation if required

                 Claim[] claims = new[]
                 {
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                 };
 
                 context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
 
                 context.Success();
 
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             },
             OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
             {
                 context.Fail("Invalid certificate");

                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             }
        };
    });
```

Since you are going to support multiple Authentication Schemes,

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Update Middleware

```
// These middleware needs to be executed first
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseCertificateForwarding();

app.UseHttpLogging();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// TODO: Other middleware
```

More read:
[Azure API Management: Self-Signed Certificate Authentication with ASP.NET Core Web API Running in an Azure Web Apps for Containers](https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2023/11/azure-api-management-self-signed.html)